# Installed Ubuntu in WSL, when I try to open anything it comes the error open: ioctl(VT_GETSTATE): Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just migrated from Mac to windows and want to continue to use the terminal to navigate the system, I installed Ubuntu, but the simple open command it is not working, can someone help me?[when I try to open a file or just enter the command open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bfVg.png)
I`m using Windows 10, version 1909.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow community, in order for us to be able to help you need to modify your question and add more details with logs if possible to the body.

Comment: Feels more like a question for superuser community rather than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1160419/how-can-i-open-a-file-from-wsl-with-the-default-application

instead of using `open`, use this:

```
cmd.exe /C start <file>
```

Then I added an alias for this command so I could still use the `open` command. How to do it is written here: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/08/create-alias-c-drive-ubuntu-bash-windows/